# Unity2d (C#) how to detect when a player clicks anywhere on the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect if a player clicks anywhere on the screen, then does some code but I can't get it to work. I've tried several different snippets of code I found online, but none of them worked.

```cs
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) && Note1.activeInHierarchy == true)
{
    PaperClose.Play();
    Note1.SetActive(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I just needed to put the detection of the mouse button inside the "void Update()" function.